# CakePHP 2.3 - How to add and update two different tables simultaneously

Tags: cakephp, saving-data, cakephp-2.3

I have two tables relevant for this matter, posts and postratings. The models have the following relationship:

`Post hasmany Postrating`
`Postrating belongsto Post`

The table schemas are:

table posts
`id | user_id | post | rating_post | ratings`

table ratings
`id | user_id | post_id | rating_post`

The idea is, that if a post exists, the user can rate it. By rating the table `ratings` gets a **new entry** and the table `posts` gets an **update** on the post entry with the id post_id.

My problem is, that I can only save new entries in both tables. I have tried it with `saveAssociated()`, but the result is the same as if I would use `saveAll()`.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Of course I will, if necessary, provide further information.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: //

Here is the method add of the PostratingsController

```
public function add($id = null) {


$this->loadModel('Post');

if (!$this->Post->exists($id)) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Postrating->create();
    if ($this->Postrating->save($this->request->data)) {
        if ($this->Postrating->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Postrating->Post->id = $id;
            $this->Postrating->Post->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The postrating has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The postrating could not be saved.'));
    }
} else {
    $options = array('conditions' => array('Post.' . $this->Post->primaryKey => $id));
    $this->request->data = $this->Post->find('first', $options);
}

$post = $this->Postrating->Post->find('list');
$users = $this->Postrating->User->find('list');
$this->set(compact('posts', 'users'));

$options = array('conditions' => array('Post.' . $this->Post->primaryKey => $id));
$this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('first', $options));
```

}

Comment: what's `rating_post` and `ratings`?

Comment: Does the form contain the 'id' of the post? Also, as you're not updating the post itself, you'll only have to update/insert data in the ratings table/model

Comment: 'rating_post' is the sum of all ratings. 'ratings' is the number of ratings

@thaJeztah
Yes, I grab the ID of the post via postratings/view/id.

I want to update the table posts in the fields rating_post and ratings, so I can list the best rated posts. So it is nessecary to also update the posts table

Comment: But those fields are not entered by the user and not part of the form-data. Have a look at the answer of @Ross because that's the way it should be done. The user posting a rating should *not be directly able to edit data in the Post _itself_*, only post a Rating. Your application logic should subsequently update the calculated total ratings

Comment: @thaJeztah
The fields for the Posts are hidden from the user. They are filled with the values of the post entry in the posts table.

Comment: you are saving `Postrating` twice

Comment: Also, you're loading the post twice if no form has been sent, and you're not using the result for `$this->Postrating->Post->find('list')` because you're using a singular $post variable there. In short, many possible errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure mean simultaneous? Assuming your `rating` is a number (e.g. between 1 and 5) and you want to store the "total" rating in your post table. I'd do something like (pseudo code)

```
if($this->Rating->saveRating($user_id, $post_id, $rating)) {
    $this->Rating->Post->id = $post_id; // update instead of insert
    $this->Rating->Post->updateRating($rating);
}
```

E.g.:

- User Rates Post with a rating of 5
- Check if user has already rated this post
- Save the Rating
- Update the Post table with the new rating (`existing_rating + new_rating`)

Comment: I have posted the add method. It is still the same. In This case the postrating would be saved but the post is not updated.

Comment: the above is one of the correct ways to do this. You can't just past `$this->request->data` to `save()` with no regard for what's happening - the data must be in the correct format with the correct keys. Post a dump of `$this->request->data`.